# How do I specify multiple column name in a Django search field?

Tags: django-rest-framework, filtering

i use django filter backend
I define multiple columns in a search field, as follows:

```
class tableViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    queryset = table.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WebSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter)
    search_fields = ('name','family','tel',)
```

i want to make an api that handle some query like this:
   select * from table1 where name like ('tom') and family like ('%anderson%') and tel like ('%0223654%')

Is there any way to specify the column name in the API?

For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/api-user/table/search?name=tom&family=andeson&tel=0223455
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use `DjangoFilterBackend` instead of `SearchFilter` if you want to filter per specific attribute.

As you are not looking for exact search, you will have to create a [`FilterSet`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters) and use [`filter_class`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filter-class) in you view.

Something like:

```
class TableFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    family = django_filters.CharFilter(name='family', lookup_expr='icontains')
    tel = django_filters.CharFilter(name='tel', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = table
        fields = ['name', 'family', 'tel']

class tableViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    queryset = table.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WebSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter)
    filter_class = TableFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the field in the query string is unnecessary. The following request should work:

```
http://127.0.0.1/api-user/table?search=something
```

[relevant docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter)

Comment: but i need to specify column in search field
for example i want to search for a field name like ('%tom%') and family like('%anderson%')

http://127.0.0.1/api-user/table/?search?name=%tom%&family=%anderson%